# Unable to use UserProfile in MVC 4 template within an Entity Framework Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a custom model (for example a blog post) which is related to the entity 'UserProfile' that is used by the WebSecurity functionality used in the MVC 4 template for registration and oAuth authentication.

Example below:

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
}
```

I am able to correctly associate the current UserProfile to a blog post like so:

```
post.User = user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.ToLower() == WebSecurity.CurrentUserName);
db.Posts.Add(post);
db.SaveChanges();
```

But when i try to get the Blog post from the database, i get a null object for the user:

```
var post = db.Posts.Where(x => x.Id == postId).FirstOrDefault();
post.User is null!
```

I believe this is because of the relationships created in the database when the SimpleMembershipProvider is created with:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

I'm sure there must be a way to ignore these or add an attribute to the User property on my blog class to overcome this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the User property has to be virtual in order to be lazy loadable by EF.

    public **virtual** UserProfile User { get; set; }

Comment: Just tested it and that's solved my problem! Thank you for your help. Can mark you as providing the answer if i answer my own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using eager loading (e.g. by using .include), you have to make the User property **virtual**, so it can be lazy loaded by EF (per default lazy loading is enabled for a DataContext - so if you did not change this, lazy loading should work).

```
public class Post
{
    ...
    public virtual UserProfile User { get; set; } // navigation properties need to be virtual to support lazy loading
    ...
}
```

If you do not want lazy loading, you need to **include** the Navigation (and perform **eager loading**) property, for example:

```
var postWithUser = db.Posts
                           .Include(p => p.User)
                           .Where(x => x.Id == postId)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

You may find [this article on lazy / eager loading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) interesting (or just google for EF and lazy/eager loading)